# Carto Builder Search Bar Not Working For Coordinates

Tags: carto, coordinates, search

The default search bar on my carto builder does not provide the correct location for ANY coordinate searches, is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

CARTO's search box only provides direct geocoding (locating names such as street addresses, cities, etc), not reverse geocoding (providing location from coordinates)